# Building kernel module with Bazel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, bazel

I would like to use Bazel to build a Linux kernel module.
I have sources that contain the logic of the module: logic.c
The process I used so far:

1. compile the 'logic.c' to a logic.o or logic.a
2. execute the 'modpost' tool to generate the logic-modpost.c
3. compile the output of the 'modpost' tool 'logic-modpost.c' to 'logic-modpost.o' or logic-modpost.a'
4. link everything together with 'ld -r'

Before I start making this work with Skylark, I was wondering if there is a well known recipe that I don't know of and if it can be shared.

I also noticed that the *cpp fragment* does not expose the 'ld' tool, I was wondering why is that? I know I can use the 'gcc' with -Xlinker or -Wl, to achieve almost the same, but it would have been nice to get access to the ld.

-- John

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there's no existing recipe.  However, if you can link everything with `g++` (instead of `ld` directly), you could do this as a macro like:

```
def mod(name, srcs, deps):
  cc_library(
      name = "%s-1" % name,
      srcs = srcs,
      deps = deps,
  )
  genrule(
      name = "%s-modpost" % name,
      srcs = ["%s-1.so" % name],
      tools = ["//path/to:modpost"],
      cmd = "$(location //path/to:modpost) $(location :%s-1.so) $@" % name,
      outs = ["%s-modpost.c"],
 )
 cc_library(
      name = "%s-2" % name,
      srcs = [":%s-modpost.c" % name],
      deps = deps,
 )
 genrule(
      name = "%s" % name,
      srcs = ["%s-2.a" % name],
      cmd = "$(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -Wlr $(location :%s-2.a) -o $@" % name,
      outs = ["%s.so" % name],
 )
```

If you want/need to use Skylark, I don't think there's any reason we can't expose `ld`, it just hasn't happened yet.  You could [file a bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues) or make a pull request adding a `@SkylarkCallable` annotation to [`getLdExecutable()`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CppConfiguration.java#L1294).